# Difference between enable_irq_wake and enable_irq

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, irq

My driver is using irq which can wake up the device, enable_irq_wake is enough or i need to first enable_irq and then set enable_irq_wake. 
Looked into the definition of these functions, not able to understand much.

I tried using both the combination it does not seem to have any effect. I mean just use enable_irq_wake and in other case use enable_irq then enable_irq_wake.

Thank you

Comment: share the driver code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/interrupt.h#L354), you'll see that `enable_irq_wake` invokes `set_irq_wake_real` that does not enable the irq.

Further more, take for example this [driver](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/input/keyboard/omap4-keypad.c): they enable/disable_irq the irq at open/close, while they enable/disable_irq_wake at suspend/resume.